# PHP Why the difference when using http before $SERVER variables?

Tags: php

I've googled and googled and am stumped.

I am trying to capture the url of a page after logging into the proxy

url of page before proxy login:

```
https://example.org/mypage.php
```

url of page after proxy login:

```
https ://example-org.proxy.example.org/mypage.php
```

When I try to capture the url using

```
$lnk = "https ://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']";
```

the output is as desired:

```
https ://example-org.proxy.example.org/mypage.php
```

When I leave off the https:// and just capture the $SERVER variables the output lacks the proxy part of the url.

```
$lnk = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

output:

```
example.org/mypage.php
```

The latter makes sense as if I dump the $SERVER array I see that the the proxy part of the url missing.  How is it finding the proxy info in the first example?

Update:
I've used an incogneto window in Chrome and tried it on IE, same behavior.
I tried the following
$lnk = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$lnk2 = "https://".$lnk;

echoing out both variables give the same results as above.  If I change the http:// to 'bla' or 'bla://' $lnk and $lnk2 both show the expected non proxied url.  It appears that http:// and https:// are changing this somehow and for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected through the proxy when testing the second example?

Comment: does your proxy handle https? it'd have to be configured pretty carefully to be able to proxy an SSL connection, and (probably) need client-side hacks as well.

Comment: The value of `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` can't change depending on the other parts of the string you interpolate it into.

Comment: Yes I am connected through the proxy and yes it accepts https. I logged into the proxy and reloaded the page which displayed both versions of the variable on the page.

Comment: Barmar it does make no sense to me either.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the suggestion but I am still getting the same results.  I've dumped all environment and php variables and am still not finding where this is coming from.  I've had a coworker try on their computer in case it was something specific to my browser but they had the same results.

Comment: https proxy, ough...

Comment: Instead of adding "SOLVED" and stuff, just post this as **answer** to your own question. This is how such things should be handled here

Comment: Marcin thanks for the info.  I've done as you've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the proxy was likely doing a search and replace on the stream. I added a couple of lines of code to print the contents of $lnk2 to a file right after creation and sure enough it lacked the proxied url as expected. Glad to know I wasn't going crazy.